# Configuring DHCP Pooling with Networkd

Tags: networking, ipv6, systemd, archlinux, dhcp

I am attempting to configure the network on my Base image for the small network I am rolling out. I would like to use IPv6, both for the reason that its superior to v4 and also because its good practice for larger enterprise scale solutions. Not to mention, I personally find some of the security baggage of IPv4 and ICMP to be tedious.

The issue is, in the Networking files, I can't seem to work out the proper configuration for utilizing the ICMPv6 in networkd without using the same SLACC address configured when the device comes up, nor can I work out how to define a proper DHCP pool. It would seem that RA are a bit crude, and I don't like the sloppy way their requirements about network boundaries interfere with other objectives.

The current network design is a pair of VLANs, one representing the fd00::/96 network, and one representing the rest of fd00::/8.

Presently, I have the same address fd00::1/8 and fd00::1/96 assigned to my gateway for ease of routing domains and letting my DNS run routing agnostic like it should. The fd00::/96 network represents the static network address block. In fact, and will be where addresses for gateways to other enclaves, as well all the standard network services like DNS and NTP live.

What I can not determine, is how to advertise a prefix for dynamically assigned devices living in the larger fd00::/8 network, such that they can be trusted to assign themselves a legal address outside the reserved address range, and more importantly, how to instruct other devices in the VLAN to reject the addresses of those devices as off-link.

The closest i could get was to just block out a series of other /96 addresses and distribute them each as prefixes, but the result was every devices just assigned itself an address in each network.

Regardless, does networkd contain a proper DHCPv6 server model, and if not, how do I get it to cooperate with a second application with regard to proper on-link assessment. Additionally, how do you configure networkd to cooperate with ICMPv6, while using a local scope address other than something from the fe80:: block, in this case a different reserved netblock fd00::/8

Comment: "_The current network design is a pair of VLANs, one representing the fd00::/96 network, and one representing the rest of fd00::/8._" That is a misuse of ULA. You are allowed to assign addressing in the `fd00::/8` range, but the next 40 bits must be randomly chosen, giving you a `/48` prefix from which you get 65,536 standard `/64` networks ([there are real reasons to only use `/64` networks](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/34172/8499)).

Comment: The gateway address for IPv6 is the link-local address of the gateway, and it is advertised in the RAs by the gateway. Also, `fd00::1/8` and `fd00::1/96` are the same address, just like  `10.0.0.1/8` and `10.0.0.1/24` are the same IPv4 address. You should also refer to _[RFC 4890, Recommendations for Filtering ICMPv6 Messages in Firewalls](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4890)_ to learn which ICMPv6 messages you must allow (IPv6 depends heavily on ICMPv6).

Comment: It sounds like you really want to use IPv6 Prefix Delegation. There are a few RFCs around that. For example _[RFC 3633, IPv6 Prefix Options for Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) version 6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3633)_, _[RFC 3769, Requirements for IPv6 Prefix Delegation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3769)_, _[RFC 6603, Prefix Exclude Option for DHCPv6-based Prefix Delegation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6603.html)_, etc.

Comment: @<Ron Maupin> The /8 is there in leui of a proper /48 because it's a base image and it will be changed to reflect which domain the device actually lives in. Also, the addresses are assigned to two separate virtual interfaces, and then rely on the route specificity to send traffic to the correct VLAN. Lastly, I'll check the documentation you provided, but I haven't seen anything to reflect a round robin distribution, or how to distribute RAs marked to only enter one network but consider all of them as on-link even when using a different prefix

Comment: Oh, and Prefix delegation is explicitly not what I want. I want the rest of the unused space above fd00::/96 up until whever ever I need the next netblock, probably somewhere around fd00::2:0:0:0:0. I suppose I could distribute one prefix for performing on link determinations, then choose an arbitrary netblock above fd00::/96 to use for autoconfig, and leave a big gaping hole. I don't like it but I suppose it would do the trick

Comment: You really, really do not want to use `/96` networks. The real way to do it is to use one of the /64 networks of the `/48` prefix for whatever you want for static or transit, or whatever. You can then use others from the prefix for other "special" things, and assign `/64` networks automatically using IPv6 prefix delegation to other networks/VLANs. The gateways for the networks are the gateway link-local addresses (`fe80::/64`) of the gateways on the link in the RAs. It really is pretty simple and automatic. Trying to apply IPv4-thinking is detrimental.